# Convert lines of text into Todos or Check boxes in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I'm trying to convert lines of text into Todos or check box items in org-mode. For example, if I have:

> Line 1
>
> Line 2
>
> Line 3

I would like to convert that to either

> *TODO Line 1
>
> *TODO Line 2
>
> *TODO Line 3

or

> - [ ] Line 1
> - [ ] Line 2
> - [ ] Line 3

I know that `C-c -` will convert the selected area into a list ([source](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html)):

> - Line 1
> - Line 2
> - Line 3

But is there any way to convert it into a list with check boxes (or alternatively, lines of Todos?)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you use `C-x C-r C-t` or define a macro for this?

Comment: @SlavenRezic, I like built in ways, but that key combo put me in some kind of `read-only` mode. From http://orgmode.org/orgcard.txt in the "Structured Editing" section, I found C-c * to convert lines to section. I'm going to look for a way to convert lines to TODOs. But the answer below by abo-abo has key strokes for checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry, this should be `C-x r t` (command string-rectangle).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use this function to make the current line(s) into
checkbox(es):

### upd: works on regions too

```
(defun org-set-line-checkbox (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((n (or arg 1)))
    (when (region-active-p)
      (setq n (count-lines (region-beginning)
                           (region-end)))
      (goto-char (region-beginning)))
    (dotimes (i n)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (insert "- [ ] ")
      (forward-line))
    (beginning-of-line)))
```

So now, starting with:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

With <kbd>C-3 C-c c</kbd> you get:

```
- [ ] Line 1
- [ ] Line 2
- [ ] Line 3
```

Now with <kbd>C-c C-*</kbd> you can get:

```
* TODO Line 1
* TODO Line 2
* TODO Line 3
```

### upd: the built-in way

Starting with

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

With <kbd>C-x h C-u C-c -</kbd> you get:

```
- Line 1
- Line 2
- Line 3
```

After, with <kbd>C-x h C-u C-c C-x C-b</kbd> you get:

```
- [ ] Line 1
- [ ] Line 2
- [ ] Line 3
```

But this is rather unwieldy, `org-set-line-checkbox` from above
should be faster.

Comment: Thanks @abo-abo! I'm surprised this wasn't build into org-mode already. I'd be surprised if I were the first person who wanted a feature like this. I'm not terribly fluent in writing functions for emacs yet. How would one modify your function so I could just do C-c c for some selected area of text and all those lines would turn into check boxes?

Comment: Thanks again @abo-abo. BTW, you can do `C-c -` instead of `C-x h C-u C-c -` with org's built in functionality :-)

Comment: C-u C-c C-c also works like C-u C-c C-x C-b for making list items into checkbox items. So selecting the whole list and pressing C-u C-c C-c should yield the same results.

Comment: @Sardtok,  `C-u C-c C-c` only works when you have selected a region of a list, and the point is located at the first item in the list.  `C-u C-c C-x C-b` works for any selected region of a list, regardless of where the point is located.  This information is documented at http://orgmode.org/manual/Checkboxes.html.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple way to do this is by [following the instructions here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Inserting-text-at-the-beginning-of-each-line.html):

> "To do this to a region, use *string-insert-rectangle*. Set the mark
>   (*C-*) at the beginning of the first line you want to prefix,
>   move the cursor to last line to be prefixed, and type *M-x*
>   *string-insert-rectangle* . To do this for the whole buffer, type *C-x h M-x* *string-insert-rectangle* ."

Example of string could be used for your TO DO list: "* TODO "

Org Mode understands this string as a TODO item.

Answer (score 2):

I highlight the region and then do `C-c -` and then re-highlight and do `C-u C-c C-x C-b`.